# continuous scolling ticker - avoiding jumping?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to get an infinite scrolling ticker type of thing working smoothly.
To make it continuous I am removing the first element and replacing it at the back once it is out of view, but this makes the container element jump a little in the amount of time it takes to reposition the element.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/rFwfN/

is there anyway around this? is there a better way of making this scrolling element continuous?
I thought of cloning the set of elements so there are two, so making the dom switch less frequent.

Comment: cloning all the elements seems better: http://jsfiddle.net/RZe9E/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rFwfN/6/

You need to reset position before injecting:

```
var scrollone = function() {
  $('carousel').tween('left',[0, (60 *-1)]);
  $('carousel').setStyle('left', '0px').getFirst().inject($('carousel'));  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  $('carousel').getFirst().inject($('carousel')); 
  $('carousel').tween('left',[0, (60 *-1)]);
```

Not sure how to do with mootools. Tween must stop before element injection and begin once injection is done.